# Why is it necessary to `exec` after `pivot_root` to unmount the old root filesystem?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, chroot, container

**Synopsis**:

`pivot_root new_root put_old`

**Question**:

Why is it necessary to execute `exec` to change the running executable in order to unmount the old root filesystem (`put_old`)?

Suppose `put_old` is moved to a directory not inside the new root filesystem (`new_root`). Is it possible to unmount it then?

Why is `chroot` needed after executing `pivot_root`? `new_root` is already made the new root filesystem at this point.

Finally, how can `pivot_root` change the root directory of the parent process (e.g. `bash`), if it has been forked from the shell? Shouldn't the change only affect the `pivot_root` process itself? Does "current process" in the `man` page refer to the parent process or `pivot_root` itself?

**Example**:

```
mount /dev/hda1 /new-root
cd /new-root
pivot_root . old-root
exec chroot . sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1
umount /old-root
```

`man pivot_root`:

> Note  that  `exec chroot` changes the running executable, which is
> necessary if the old root directory should be  unmounted  afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q:** Why is it necessary to execute `exec` to change the running executable in order to unmount the old root filesystem (`put_old`)?

Because filesystems cannot be unmounted when they are busy, and if a running executable (e.g. `bash`) or its shared libraries are on the old root filesystem they would keep it busy.

---

> **Q:** Suppose `put_old` is moved to a directory not inside the new root filesystem (`new_root`). Is it possible to unmount it then?

It's not allowed for *put_old* to be outside *new_root*. From the [manual page for the system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html):

> *put_old* must be at or underneath *new_root*

---

> **Q:** Why is `chroot` needed after executing `pivot_root`? `new_root` is already made the new root filesystem at this point.

It isn't needed any more. The [original manual page](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man2/pivot_root.2?id=fea681dafb1363a154b7fc6d59baa83d2a9ebc5c) for the system call was [substantially rewritten in 2019](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/620c691a-065e-b894-4f06-7453012bc8d3@gmail.com/)<sup>[[alternative link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/9/23/286)]</sup>, and the updated manual page<sup>[[archive link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man2/pivot_root.2?id=ae6b221882ce71ba82fcdbe02419a225111502f0)][[alternative link](https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/blob/ae6b221882ce71ba82fcdbe02419a225111502f0/man2/pivot_root.2)]</sup> explains the behaviour and the historical uncertainty:

> `pivot_root()` changes the root directory and the current working directory of each process or thread in the same mount namespace to *new_root* if they point to the old root directory.
>
> ...
>
> [This behavior] is necessary in order to prevent kernel threads from keeping the old root mount busy with their root and current working directories[...]
>
> ...
>
> **Historical notes**
>
> For many years, this manual page carried the following text:
>
> > `pivot_root()` may or may not change the current root and
> > the current working directory of any processes or threads
> > which use the old root directory.  The caller of
> > `pivot_root()` must ensure that processes with root or
> > current working directory at the old root operate
> > correctly in either case.  An easy way to ensure this is
> > to change their root and current working directory to
> > *new_root* before invoking `pivot_root()`.
>
> This text, written before the system call implementation was even
> finalized in the kernel, was probably intended to warn users at
> that time that the implementation might change before final
> release.  However, the behavior stated in DESCRIPTION has
> remained consistent since this system call was first implemented
> and will not change now.

---

> **Q:** Finally, how can `pivot_root` change the root directory of the parent process (e.g. `bash`), if it has been forked from the shell? Shouldn't the change only affect the `pivot_root` process itself? Does "current process" in the `man` page refer to the parent process or `pivot_root` itself?

This is because `pivot_root()` operates on the *mount namespace* of the calling process, which is shared with the parent process. The manual page for the utility ([pivot_root(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pivot_root.8.html)) doesn't state this clearly, but the updated manual page for the system call ([pivot_root(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html)) does (emphasis added):

> `pivot_root()` changes the root mount *in the mount namespace* of the calling process. [...]
>
> `pivot_root()` changes the root directory and the current working directory of *each process or thread* in the same mount namespace to *new_root* if they point to the old root directory.

Comment: Thank you. If `pivot_root(2)` operates on the mount namespace, and multiple processes are running in that namespace, it's very likely that after calling `exec(2)`, other processes will still be running binaries on the old root filesystem? In that case, it won't be possible to `umount(2)` the old root filesystem, since it's busy?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to call `exec(2)`, if the process' binary is not located on the old root filesystem?

Comment: Do kernel threads also have root and current directories? They are not namespaced,  right?

Comment: (1) Yes, if other processes are running binaries from the old root fs it will be busy. (2) Yes, `exec` is not necessary if the process' binary *and shared libraries* are not on the old root fs. Debugging tip: *fuser* can identify open files in some cases. (3) Yes, kernel threads have root and current directories, and even namespaces. For example the kernel thread *kdevtmpfs* [uses a new mount namespaces](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c1e2e0350ce3/drivers/base/devtmpfs.c#L412) (compare `readlink "/proc/$(pgrep -x kdevtmpfs)/ns/mnt"` and `readlink "/proc/$(pgrep -x kthreadd)/ns/mnt"`).

Comment: let me mention also why `cd /new-root` is useful : because a filesystem is busy also when a process has its cwd in it